# MYSQL calculate time between rows and group as sessions

Tags: mysql, datetime

My data looks like this;

```
datetime
2014-12-28 07:26:29
2014-12-28 07:25:29
2014-12-28 07:24:29
2014-12-28 07:23:30
2014-12-28 07:22:29
2014-12-28 00:19:49
2014-12-27 22:24:52 * end
2014-12-27 22:23:52
2014-12-27 22:22:52
2014-12-27 22:21:52
2014-12-27 22:20:52 * start
```

I want the output to be like;

```
datetime_start         datetime_end             duration_in_mins
2014-12-28 07:22:29    2014-12-28 07:26:29      4
2014-12-28 00:19:49    2014-12-28 00:19:49      1
2014-12-27 22:20:52    2014-12-27 22:24:52      4
```

So if the next row is 1 minute after the other one, it's still considered part of the same session. Any ideas?

Comment: This would be very hard to do with SQL, if the business rules are based on data from a different row.  One ideas that you might want to think about is adding a session field, and then setting that field, possibly in a background process.

Comment: @BrianHoover That's fighting talk ;-)

Comment: I can't imagine it not being possible to be honest.. Unfortunatly I don't have the option to set the session in the background..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be exactly right, but something along these lines should work...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(datetime DATETIME NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);


INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('2014-12-28 07:26:29'),
('2014-12-28 07:25:29'),
('2014-12-28 07:24:29'),
('2014-12-28 07:23:30'),
('2014-12-28 07:22:29'),
('2014-12-28 00:19:49'),
('2014-12-27 22:24:52'),
('2014-12-27 22:23:52'),
('2014-12-27 22:22:52'),
('2014-12-27 22:21:52'),
('2014-12-27 22:20:52');

SELECT MIN(a.datetime) start
     , MAX(a.datetime) end
     , TIMEDIFF(MAX(a.datetime)+INTERVAL 1 MINUTE,MIN(a.datetime)) diff
  FROM
     ( SELECT x.* 
     , MAX(y.datetime) a
     , MAX(y.datetime) < x.datetime - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE session
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.datetime < x.datetime 
 GROUP
    BY x.datetime
     ) a
  JOIN (SELECT @session := 1) vars
GROUP BY CASE WHEN session = 1 THEN @session := @session + 1 ELSE @session := @session END;

+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| start               | end                 | diff     |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
| 2014-12-27 22:21:52 | 2014-12-27 22:24:52 | 00:04:00 |
| 2014-12-28 00:19:49 | 2014-12-28 00:19:49 | 00:01:00 |
| 2014-12-28 07:22:29 | 2014-12-28 07:22:29 | 00:01:00 |
| 2014-12-28 07:23:30 | 2014-12-28 07:26:29 | 00:03:59 |
+---------------------+---------------------+----------+
```

Comment: Cute.  I stand corrected.  I was thinking about something like that ,but didn't put in the effort

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for me would be to use a script to traverse the table once and build the output table, but if this is not possible for you, you can get the same with nested queries, like this:

(assume a schema: `` CREATE TABLE Table1 (`dt` datetime) ``

To select the beginnings of the sessions:

```
SELECT dt AS s_start 
FROM Table1 start 
WHERE Timestampdiff(minute, (select max(dt) from Table1 m where m.dt < start.dt), start.dt ) > 1;
```

Selecting the endings of the sessions is similiar.

Then combine it to select beginnings of the session with earliest ending of the session:

```
SELECT dt AS s_start,
(SELECT min(s_end_1) FROM
   (SELECT e_1.dt AS s_end_1 
   FROM Table1 e_1 
   WHERE Timestampdiff(minute, e_1.dt, (select min(dt) from Table1 t where t.dt > e_1.dt) ) > 1 ) e
 WHERE e.s_end_1 > start.dt) as s_end
FROM Table1 start 
WHERE Timestampdiff(minute, (select max(dt) from Table1 m where m.dt < start.dt), start.dt ) > 1;
```

Pay attention to borderline conditions (first, last session, session with only single row as in your example) and adjust the code. Good luck.